# How to use the word abuse as a countable noun?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, nouns, spoken-english, uncountable-nouns

> Holding animals in captivity is considered abuse.

or

> Holding animals in captivity is considered an abuse.

I am confused about having an article or no article before the word abuse. I am confused about how to recognise and use nouns that are both countable and uncountable.

Comment: Generally, a dictionary will tell you if a noun is countable or not, or is both.

Comment: But it is apparent the the OP already knows that "abuse" is "both countable and non-countable" But is unsure when to treat it as a countable noun and when to treat it as non-count.

Comment: Uncountable nouns are sometimes used in a countable sense. For example, "abuse" is uncountable, but there can be different forms of "abuse" (such as in the legal context). People go to spas to "take in the waters" meaning the specific waters at that spa. "Information" is uncountable, but it is acceptable to say, "Based on the information..." because you are talking about specific information.